# What would cause "Device not ready (errno=-16), forcing hardreset?

Tags: linux

```
kernel: [7179486.983633] res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
kernel: [7179492.314726] ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
kernel: [7179497.408202] ata1: device not ready (errno=-16), forcing hardreset
kernel: [7179497.408217] ata1: soft resetting link
kernel: [7179500.160267] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
kernel: [7179500.160267] ata1: EH complete
kernel: [7179500.164272] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 976773168 512-byte hardware sectors (500108 MB)
kernel: [7179500.164272] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
```

Those are the messages we're getting on a server running MySQL, apache, and a few other web programs.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7):

It seems that your hard disk had a hiccup and didn't respond in the time that the kernel wanted. If this is a one time event, I wouldn't worry too much, as it appears that after a reset, the operation completed. If it happens often, I would consider replacing your hard disk. Investigate the smartctl tool to check the health of your hard disk. I hope you are using RAID on this server, so your disk is not a single point of failure.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response, and I am definitely gonna look into this! Thanks!